# Make indicator for date using `timeDate`

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a number of dates for which I would like to make an indicator variable for. The problem is that I am having difficulty making this happen in `R` using `timeDate`. Here is a toy example

```
library(timeDate)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

>df <- tribble(
  ~date,
  "2010-12-31",
  "2011-01-01",
  "2011-01-02") %>% 
  mutate(date = ymd(date))

> df
# A tibble: 3 x 1
  date      
  <date>    
1 2010-12-31
2 2011-01-01
3 2011-01-02
```

I would like to add an indicator for New Years Day called `is_new_year`.

I tried the following

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(is_new_year = ifelse(USNewYearsDay(year = year(date)) == date,1,0))
```

and got the error

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types.

What should I do to get

```
  date          is_new_year
  <date>         <int>
1 2010-12-31       0
2 2011-01-01       1
3 2011-01-02       0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres an solution:

```
# dummy dates 
x <- seq(as.Date("1900-01-01"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), by = "day")
# first date of year
first <- subset(x, format(as.Date(x),"%m")==12 & format(as.Date(x),"%d")==31)+1
# find if df dates == first date of year 
find <- df$date %in% first
df$find <- ifelse(find == TRUE,1,0)

df
```

with the output:

```
> df
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  date        find
  <date>     <dbl>
1 2010-12-31  0   
2 2011-01-01  1.00
3 2011-01-02  0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 df%>%mutate(is.newyear=as.numeric(as.Date(paste0(year(date),"-1-1"))==date))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
        date is.newyear
      <date>      <dbl>
1 2010-12-31          0
2 2011-01-01          1
3 2011-01-02          0
```

Comment: This does work for this one example, but I plan on using the `timeDate` packages since there are many holidays I would like to look at.

Comment: is `timeDate` similar to `holidays` package?

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.